# Show weights in JgraphT

Tags: java, graphing, jgrapht

I have implemented this Graph:

```
ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph<String, MyWeightedEdge> g = 
    new ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph<String, MyWeightedEdge>(MyWeightedEdge.class);
```

In order to show what the class name says; a simple listenable directed weighted graph. I want to change the label of the edges and instead of the format

```
return "(" + source + " : " + target + ")";
```

I want it to show the weight of the edge. I realise that all actions on the nodes, e.g. the `getEdgesWeight()` method, are delegated from the graph and not the edge. How can I show the weight of the edge? Do I have to pass in the Graph to the edge somehow?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the class MyWeightedEdge already contains a method such as

```
public void setWeight(double weight)
```

If this is indeed the case, then what you need to do is:

Derive your own subclass from *ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph* (e.g., *ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph*). I would add both constructor versions, delegating to "super" to ensure compatibility with the original  class.

Create the graph as in your question, but using the new class

```
ListenableDirectedWeightedGraph g = 
    new CustomListenableDirectedWeightedGraph(
        MyWeightedEdge.class);
```

Override the method *setEdgeWeight* as follows:

```
public void setEdgeWeight(E e, double weight) {
    super.setEdgeWeight(e, weight);
    ((MyWeightedEdge)e).setWeight(weight);
}
```

And, last but not least, override the *toString* method of the class *MyWeightedEdge* to return the label you want the edge to have (presumably including the weight, which is now available to it).

I hope this helps.

Comment: user5915 didn't mention what he used to visualize his graph but I assume it was jgraph. It's like you're telling him to write his own library O.o